# git config file permission lost after `git remote set-url origin https://`

Tags: linux, git, file, permissions, capistrano

I was using `capistrano` for the deployment `cap production deploy`, the error message from `capistrano`

```
 DEBUG [3730481e]       fatal: unable to access './config': Permission denied
```

I found it's because the file permission lost.

the `repo/config` file permission 0664 before

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 ec ec 217 Mar  1 12:08 config
```

after  `git remote set-url origin https://myawesometoken:@github.com/myawesomeusername/myawesomeproject.git`

the `repo/config` file permission was lost, 0000

```
----------  1 ec ec 217 Mar  1 12:09 config
```

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://myawesometoken:@github.com/myawesomeusername/myawesomeproject.git
        fetch = +refs/*:refs/*
        mirror = true
```

Comment: What is the current `umask` ?

Comment: @phd Hi,  `su ec`   then `umask` returns  `0022`

Comment: Did you use `su ec` for `git` and `cap`?

Comment: @phd yes, always under user `ec`